# django + session var not transferring between views

Tags: django, session, view

Once I submit my form in my home view we are redirected to my download view which has a false response for my session var... why??? I am unsure how to fix this issue and it feels like I've tried everything.

```
@login_required
def Home(request):
    form = TimeForm()
    search_times = []
    if request.method == "POST":

        # clear session data
        # for key in request.session.keys():
        #     test.append(request.session[key])

        start = request.POST['start_time']
        end = request.POST['end_time']
        start = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
        end = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())


        start = re.split('.[0-9]+$', str(start))[0]
        end = re.split('.[0-9]+$', str(end))[0]
        search_times.append(int(start))
        search_times.append(int(end))

        request.session['search_times'] = search_times
        request.session.save()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'search_times': search_times,
    }
    return render(request, "pcap_app/home.html", context)

def Download(request, path):
    test = []
    access_time = []
    search_times = []

    search_times = request.session.get('search_times', False)

    # testing timestamp directory listing
    files = sorted_ls(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path))
    for f in files:
        time = os.stat(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, f)).st_mtime
        access_time.append(int(re.split('.[0-9]+$', str(time))[0]))

    context = {
        'sort': files,
        'times': access_time,
        'search': search_times,
        'test': test,
    }
    return render(request, "pcap_app/downloads.html", context)
```

home.html

```
<head>
    <script                    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    {{ form.media }}
</head>
<body>
    <h1>pcap search</h1>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <form  action="/download/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    {{ search_times }}
    {{ test }}
        <a href="/logout/">Logout</a>

    {% else %}
        <a href="/login/?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a>

    {% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: Where are you redirecting in the above code? Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: I meant in the above view, where is the code for redirection. Also, what code snippet is getting executed in case of `POST` request.

Comment: the code for redirect is within my home.html, the action for the form

Comment: Please post the code for `home.html` where the form is there.

Comment: done. added .html file

Comment: the download.html file is just referencing variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **wrongly set the `action` attribute in your `home.html` template as `/download/`**.

When you submit the form, the `POST` request is submitted to the `/download/` view and not the `home` view. So, the code for setting the session is never executed.

You need to change the `action` attribute to your `home` view url. When you do this, in case of `POST` requests, the variable `search_times` will be set in the session.

```
 <form  action="/home/url/" method="POST">
```

After specifying the `action` attribute in `home.html`, you will need to redirect to `/download/` in `home` view. Then after the redirection happens to your `download` view, you will be access the `search_times` vaiable in the session.

```
@login_required
def Home(request):
    form = TimeForm()
    search_times = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
        request.session['search_times'] = search_times # set the variable in the session
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/download/') # redirect to download page

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'search_times': search_times,
    }
    return render(request, "pcap_app/home.html", context)
```

Comment: TY :) I deleted the string in my form action and added a url redirect within my view

Answer (score 3):

Try save session

```
request.session.save()
```